# Positioning a table at a specific location

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a macro to allow a user to select an office branch from a combo box, and now I want to insert the relevant address into the word document at a specific location. I have it using a table to hold the address, however when the table is created, it is created at wherever position the cursor just happens to be sitting at on the page.

I can't seem to find a way to tell the table to position exactly (x,y) where I need it to appear. Since there is nothing else in the document but text, there is nothing to reference to.

I am also trying to stay away from using Active X controls if at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

This code will add a three column, one row table between the second and third paragraphs.

```
Sub InsertTable()

    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim pg As Paragraph

    With ThisDocument
        'Add a new paragraph that the table will replace
        Set pg = .Paragraphs.Add(.Paragraphs(3).Range)
        'Add a table in place of the new paragraph
        Set tbl = .Tables.Add(pg.Range, 1, 3)
    End With

    tbl.Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "123 Main St"
    tbl.Columns(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = "City"
    tbl.Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = "State"
    tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 41

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for this suggestion. I got it working more or less, but the trouble I am having now is positioning it horizontally on the page. I was thinking that maybe I could use indents or something to that effect, but that didn't seem to work at all. I centered the table, but alas that gets it close but not close enough. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the LeftIndent property of Rows.  I edited the code to give you an example.  If you want to get really fancy with the table formatting, record a macro and format it how you want manually.  The recorded macro will give you the objects, properties, and methods you need to manipulate.

Comment: I had trouble with the with statements, so I made a version without the with statement in an [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58049955/2089396) @DickKusleika feel free to include it in your answer directly

Answer (score 1):

You may use this to position table both horizontally and vertically

```
tbl.Rows.HorizontalPosition = 150 'In points
tbl.Rows.VerticalPosition = 200
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble grasping the code with the with-statement from [Dick Kusleika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901193/2089396), so I'd like to share my version without the with-statement, for people like me much easier to understand:

```
Sub InsertTable()

Dim tbl As Table
Dim pg As Paragraph

'Add a new paragraph that the table will replace
Set pg = ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Add(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range)
'Add a table in place of the new paragraph
Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables.Add(pg.Range, 1, 3)

tbl.Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "123 Main St"
tbl.Columns(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = "City"
tbl.Columns(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = "State"
tbl.Rows.LeftIndent = 41

End Sub
```